# Strapi Blog + React Frontend. Fetch API clarification

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api, strapi

I am trying to create a blog using Strapi as a cms and React for the front end. I've been playing around and trying to get everything connected and am having some trouble understanding why when I save the json in state without drilling into it using `setPosts(json);` I can't seem to access it when I render using `return <div className="test">{posts.data[0].attributes.Title}</div>;`.

However if I save the the attributes in state with `setPosts(json.data[0].attributes);`. I can access the Title using `return <div className="test">{posts.Title}</div>;` perfectly fine.

Full code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

// functional react app
const App = () => {
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
        const url = "http://localhost:1337/api/blogs";
        const options = {
            headers: {
                Authorization: process.env.REACT_APP_STRAPI_TOKEN,
            },
        };
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                const res = await fetch(url, options);
                const json = await res.json();
                // this works but would ideally like to use setPosts(json).
                setPosts(json.data[0].attributes);
                console.log(json);
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        };

        fetchData();
    }, []);
    return <div className="test">{posts.Title}</div>;
};

export default App;
```

The full response when I try and request "http://localhost:1337/api/blogs" using postman is

````
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "attributes": {
                "Title": "First Blog Post",
                "CreationDate": "2023-03-29",
                "Content": "My first blog test. Grabbing API endpoints.\n\nimage in the middle of the  text.\n```\ntest code\n```\n\n\n![Screenshot 2023-02-26 at 6.23.08 PM.png](http://localhost:1337/uploads/Screenshot_2023_02_26_at_6_23_08_PM_ca2f96ffd1.png)",
                "createdAt": "2023-03-30T02:01:59.255Z",
                "updatedAt": "2023-03-30T02:02:06.214Z",
                "publishedAt": "2023-03-30T02:02:06.123Z"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "attributes": {
                "Title": "Blog 2 ",
                "CreationDate": "2023-04-01",
                "Content": "test content 2",
                "createdAt": "2023-04-02T20:53:26.950Z",
                "updatedAt": "2023-04-02T20:53:30.963Z",
                "publishedAt": "2023-04-02T20:53:30.884Z"
            }
        }
    ],
    "meta": {
        "pagination": {
            "page": 1,
            "pageSize": 25,
            "pageCount": 1,
            "total": 2
        }
    }
}
````

I've tried several variations of saving the state and accessing it, but can't seem to figure out why I can't just save the json as is and access it.

Comment: What does this sentence mean? "I can't seem to access it when I render using" What is the value of `posts` when you use `setPosts(json)`? `console.log` it before return, but outside of `useEffect` and see how it changes

Comment: Likely problem is that you try to access properties of an empty object and it doesn't work giving you an error. You need to write your code in a way that handles "empty state" before data is loaded from the backend

Comment: The problem is that default response has an `attributes` field, and when you post you should provide data without attributes field